# I got a NaN error when using the Encog 3.0 library

Tags: java, matlab, artificial-intelligence, nan

I have a problem when build an elman recurrent neural network using encog 3.0 library. I got NaN error after few iteration.

This is my code in MATLAB :

```
net=newlrn (minmax(usdjpytrain),[4,1], {'logsig', 'purelin'}, 'trainscg', 'learngdm', 'mse'); 
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000; 
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-5;
```

I wanna to create recurrent neural network like above in java. by default, a learning rate value in MATLAB is 0.01 and momentum is 0.9. but I got **NaN** error if I use learning rate and momentum like that. this is my code in java :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package modifikasiJSR;

import org.encog.Encog;
import org.encog.engine.network.activation.ActivationSigmoid;
import org.encog.ml.data.MLDataSet;
import org.encog.ml.data.basic.BasicMLDataSet;
import org.encog.ml.train.MLTrain;
import org.encog.neural.networks.BasicNetwork;
import org.encog.neural.networks.training.CalculateScore;
import org.encog.neural.networks.training.TrainingSetScore;
import org.encog.neural.networks.training.propagation.back.Backpropagation;
import org.encog.neural.pattern.ElmanPattern;
import dataSet.DataDefault;
import database.Parameter;
import org.encog.ml.data.MLData;
import org.encog.ml.data.MLDataPair;
import org.encog.ml.train.strategy.HybridStrategy;
import org.encog.neural.networks.structure.AnalyzeNetwork;
import org.encog.neural.networks.training.propagation.scg.ScaledConjugateGradient;

/**
 *
 * @author Akmal
 */
public class MseTrain{
    private String mataUang;
    private int jumlahDataSet;
    Parameter param = new Parameter();
    private double [] bias_hid_out = new double[2];
    private double [] bias_hid_in = new double[param.getHidden_node()];
    private double [] bobot_hid_out = new double[param.getHidden_node()];
    private double [] bobot_hid_in = new double[7*param.getHidden_node()];


    public MseTrain(String mataUang){
        this.mataUang = mataUang;
    }

    static BasicNetwork createElmanNetwork() {
        // construct an Elman type network
        Parameter param = new Parameter();
        ElmanPattern pattern = new ElmanPattern();
        pattern.setActivationFunction(new ActivationSigmoid());
        pattern.setInputNeurons(7);
        pattern.addHiddenLayer(param.getHidden_node());
        pattern.setOutputNeurons(1);
        return (BasicNetwork)pattern.generate();
    }

    public void mse(double[][] data, double [][] target) {
        System.out.println("menjalankan method MSE");
        DataDefault dataSet = new DataDefault(mataUang);
        jumlahDataSet = dataSet.getJumTraining();
        final MLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(data, target);
        final BasicNetwork elmanNetwork = MseTrain.createElmanNetwork();
        final double elmanError = trainNetwork("Elman", elmanNetwork,trainingSet);
        System.out.println("Best error rate with Elman Network: " + elmanError);
        Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
    }

    private double trainNetwork(final String what,final BasicNetwork network, final MLDataSet trainingSet) {
        network.reset();
        // train the neural network
        System.out.println(network.getActivation(0));
        System.out.println(network.getActivation(1));
        System.out.println(network.getActivation(2));

        CalculateScore score = new TrainingSetScore(trainingSet);

        final MLTrain trainMain = new Backpropagation(network, trainingSet, 0.01, 0.9);
        final MLTrain trainAlt = new ScaledConjugateGradient(network, trainingSet);
        trainMain.addStrategy(new HybridStrategy(trainAlt));

        //set Bobot hid In
        network.setWeight(0, 0, 0, 3.0439);
        network.setWeight(0, 0, 1, 2.8421);
        network.setWeight(0, 0, 2, -2.8529);
        network.setWeight(0, 0, 3, 2.7013);

        network.setWeight(0, 1, 0, 1.2741);
        network.setWeight(0, 1, 1, -2.8055);
        network.setWeight(0, 1, 2, -1.6862);
        network.setWeight(0, 1, 3, 0.3049);

        network.setWeight(0, 2, 0, 4.5054);
        network.setWeight(0, 2, 1, 3.3152);
        network.setWeight(0, 2, 2, -2.6663);
        network.setWeight(0, 2, 3, 3.1311);

        network.setWeight(0, 3, 0, 4.4113);
        network.setWeight(0, 3, 1, -0.1022);
        network.setWeight(0, 3, 2, 2.2913);
        network.setWeight(0, 3, 3, -2.3347);

        network.setWeight(0, 4, 0, -1.2521);
        network.setWeight(0, 4, 1, 4.8178);
        network.setWeight(0, 4, 2, 3.6979);
        network.setWeight(0, 4, 3, 4.9682);

        network.setWeight(0, 5, 0, 1.4512);
        network.setWeight(0, 5, 1, -3.1329);
        network.setWeight(0, 5, 2, 2.5726);
        network.setWeight(0, 5, 3, 2.7323);

        network.setWeight(0, 6, 0, 2.3088);
        network.setWeight(0, 6, 1, 2.4109);
        network.setWeight(0, 6, 2, 2.4835);
        network.setWeight(0, 6, 3, -0.9406);

        //set Bias hid In
        network.setWeight(0, 7, 0, -9.3723);
        network.setWeight(0, 7, 1, -2.1356);
        network.setWeight(0, 7, 2, -5.0966);
        network.setWeight(0, 7, 3, -1.5829);

        //set Bobot Hid out
        network.setWeight(1, 0, 0, -0.6263);
        network.setWeight(1, 1, 0, -0.0205);
        network.setWeight(1, 2, 0, -0.1088);
        network.setWeight(1, 3, 0, 0.2926);

        //set Bias Hid out
        network.setWeight(1, 4, 0, 0.4187);

        int epoch = 0;
        do{
            trainMain.iteration();
            System.out.println("Training " + what + ", Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + trainMain.getError());
            System.out.println("Error:" + trainMain.getError());
            epoch++;
        }while(trainMain.getError()>0.00001&&epoch<=1);

        System.out.println("Neural Network Results:");
        for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) {
            final MLData output = network.compute(pair.getInput());
            System.out.println(
            pair.getInput().getData(0)
            + ","
            + pair.getInput().getData(1)
            + ","
            + pair.getInput().getData(2)
            + ","
            + pair.getInput().getData(3)
            + ","
            + pair.getInput().getData(4)
            + ","
            + pair.getInput().getData(5)
            + ","
            + pair.getInput().getData(6)
            + ", actual="
            + output.getData(0)
            + ",ideal="
            + pair.getIdeal().getData(0));
        }

        System.out.println("bobot : "+network.dumpWeights());

        AnalyzeNetwork bobotBias = new AnalyzeNetwork(network);
        int jumBobotIn = param.getHidden_node()*7;
        System.out.println("jumBobotIn : "+jumBobotIn);
        int indexBobotIn = 0;
        int indexBobotOut = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<bobotBias.getWeightValues().length; i++){
            System.out.println("bobot : "+bobotBias.getWeightValues()[i]);
            if(i<jumBobotIn){
                bobot_hid_in[indexBobotIn] = bobotBias.getWeightValues()[i];
                indexBobotIn++;
            }
            else{
                bobot_hid_out[indexBobotOut] = bobotBias.getWeightValues()[i];
                indexBobotOut++;
            }
        }
        int indexBiasIn = 0;
        int indexBiasOut = 0;
        int jumBiasIn = param.getHidden_node();
        for(int i=0; i<bobotBias.getBiasValues().length; i++){
            System.out.println("bias : "+bobotBias.getBiasValues()[i]);
            if(i<jumBiasIn){
                bias_hid_in[indexBiasIn] = bobotBias.getBiasValues()[i];
                indexBiasIn++;
            }
            else{
                bias_hid_out[indexBiasOut] = bobotBias.getBiasValues()[i];
                indexBiasOut++;
            }
        }
        return trainMain.getError();
    }

    /**
     * @return the bias_hid_out
     */
    public double[] getBias_hid_out() {
        return bias_hid_out;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bias_hid_in
     */
    public double[] getBias_hid_in() {
        return bias_hid_in;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bobot_hid_out
     */
    public double[] getBobot_hid_out() {
        return bobot_hid_out;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bobot_hid_in
     */
    public double[] getBobot_hid_in() {
        return bobot_hid_in;
    }
}
```

everyone please help me, I got stuck here for several days. T.T

Comment: The most likely source of a `NaN` is a computation, `0.0/0.0`, `sqrt(-1)` or whatnot. `MseTrain` seems not to contain any serious calculation. It would probably be more helpful to post the calculation code rather than a whole class.

Comment: The calculation code is inside library. do you wanna see that library ?

Comment: I'm not enthusiastic. Have you tried with different rate and momentum?

Comment: yes, I tried use rate 0.00001 and momentum 0.0. that rate didn't give me NaN error. but it will give me different weight and bias with MATLAB as the result of train. this is the calculation code : https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/neural/networks/training/propagation/GradientWorker.java

Comment: Doesn't look like the real meat. A bit of calculation, but mostly yet another wrapper around whatever. That package seems to suffer from the Matryoshka syndrome, I'm not going to scan through 1000 or so classes. Sorry that I can't be of more help.